# Searching a prefix in list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have currently a list of dictionaries

```
list_of_dicts = [{"name": 'stfdahbancssc',"status":'running'},
                 {"name": 'stfdahbancssc',"status":'running'}]
```

I want to check how can i match the prefix `'stf'` and print stf exists otherwise stf does not exist .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the dictionaries, get the "name" value, check for prefix, print message:

```
list_of_dicts = [{"name": 'stfdahbancssc',"status":'running'},
                {"name": 'stfdahbancssc',"status":'running'},
                {"name": 'none'}]

for idx,d in enumerate(list_of_dicts): 
    if d.get("name","").startswith("stf"):
        v = d["name"]
        s = d["status"]
        print(f"The {idx} dictionary has {v} as {s}")
        print("a")
    else:
        print(f"The {idx}. dictionary has no name starting with 'stf'.")
```

Output:

Comment: In case i want to also check whether the status is running or not how do i proceed to changes here . lets say another dictionary has status of error

Comment: @kshi  I suggest following https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ as a starting point and learn how to work with pythons list / dict / etc instead of moving the goal posts of your question...